# Reprojection REST Service

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, web-mapping, web-service

Are there any open source projects that offer a reprojection service over REST?  I know there are online converters available, but I want to deploy something on premises.

What I'm looking for is a service that takes coordinate information will return coordinates in another, user specified, projection.

For example, the input would be something like

```
{
   y:"27.947671",
   x:"-82.457237",
   "coordinate_notation":"decimal degrees",
   "Input_CRS":"EPSG:4326",
   "Ouput_CRS":"EPSG:26917"
}
```

And the output would be something like:

```
{
   "Ouput_CRS":"EPSG:26917",
   "y":"3071946.25",
   "x":"347881.54"
}
```

I *think* ArcGIS server has this capability.  Does GeoServer?  Are there any one-off projects that do it?

Comment: Perhaps a geoserver WPS

Comment: Not sure why you've tagged the question GeoJSON? strictly it only has one projection CRS:84, are you looking to create GeoJSON from another datasource and another projection?

Comment: nmtoken: You are correct: I shouldn't have tagged it geojson.  We're working with json and geospatial data, but not necessarily geojson.

Comment: Projecting a service on-the-fly from the original vector data is a basic capability of the ArcGIS Server service itself.  Projecting a map service (raster tiles) as a third-party service is an entirely different problem, and is likely to have both performance and image/data quality issues.

Comment: Do you have only points or also other geometries to convert?

Comment: This is only for points.